# Trying to change widgets h-tags

Tags: functions, widgets

I have created a child theme of moesia-pro-ii. The moesia theme has a widget folder with a php file named "fp-latest-news". In default this widget uses h4 tags. I want to change the h4 to h3 tags in the child theme. All I know so far is, that I have to add something to the functions.php of the child theme. Everything I tried so far(which I found on google) didn't work for that case.

Does anybody know how to solve this case?

Comment: You probably need to make a copy of the widget in the child theme with the same path structure and edit it there. But I don't know how widget templates in general, or this widget specifically, is loaded - you might have to track down that code to be sure.

Comment: It may be simpler to just edit the theme though, or look for a way to patch the CSS so that that one specific h4 - is rendered with h3 styling, e.g. adding a styles for h4s as a child of the widget's top level div by name or by class.

Comment: Thanks so far! But none of your recommendations work for me. I want to change the tag to h3 for seo reasons, not for the styling. I also tried to copy the widget to the child theme. But the changes do not apply then.